# how could I grab the text from a p tag and insert it in a href link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I have a twitter button on my page, when clicked it will take you to twitter page where you have the text area to input your message. I want the users when click on the "twitter" button to take them to twitter and the text from the

tag on the page gets automatically inserted into the textarea. This is my button

```
<div id="twitter-btn" class="center">
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-social btn-twitter " href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"> Twitter</i>
  </a> 
      </di>
```

now twitter provides their own button and documentation on how to use it.

```
<a class="twitter-share-button"
  href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world">
Tweet</a>
```

notice how the string is appended to the end of the url... here's the twitter button docs
https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button
I have a div with id of "content" and insed a

paragraph. How can grab the text form the paragraph and append to twitter url. Here's the project on codepne.io
https://codepen.io/zentech/pen/ZyyGgq?editors=1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't hide the button that you need help with. :|

Check this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/junaidkbr/pen/qjXQoW)

The code:

```
$('.btn-twitter').on( 'click', function( evt ){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var tweetURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent( $('p.sub_text').text() );
    window.open(tweetURL, '_blank');
} )
```

To have this accomplished in run time (onclick) there is just no other option but to prevent default hyperlink action and then do it the JS way.

Comment: Don't forget to use `encodeURIComponent` to do the necessary escaping.

Answer (score 1):

The way it works is, you link the user to a special URL (`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet`) with a special GET argument (`text`) which contains the text to pre-fill the tweet with.

Since your content is dynamic, you have to use JavaScript to accomplish that. You are already using jQuery to get the quote text and to blend-in the twitter button, so you should just add this to your `$('#getMessage').on("click", function() {` somewhere around `$("#twitter-btn").show();`

```
var text = encodeURIComponent($('#content').text());
$('#twitter-btn a').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + text);
```

Notice that you have to use `encodeURIComponent` in order for special characters like `?,  , &, /, ...` to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Create the link in your javascript instead.

```
<p id="quote">This is a quote</p>
<button id="tweet" type="button">Tweet</button>
```

Javascript

```
$( "#tweet" ).click(function() {
  // make the text url friendly
  var text = encodeURI($( "#quote" ).text());
  window.location.replace("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + text)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully that will work for you. I used jquery because I'm the most familiar with it. I tested it in my browser and it works for me.

```
        <div id="twitter-btn" class="center">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-social btn-twitter" target="_blank">
           <i class="fa fa-twitter"> Twitter</i>
        </button> 
    </div>

    <div id="content">bvnvcbnvbnnb</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.btn-twitter').on('click', function(){
            var content = $('#content').text();
            window.location.href = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+encodeURIComponent(content);
        });
    </script>
```